# pass JSON object into TabBarViewController

Tags: ios, json, swift

I'm working on creating an iOS application. When I click on my "login" button, the server responds by sending JSON back to the application. I know the information is being sent back because I can print the info from the LoginVC.

When a login is successful, I'd like to pass the server response "into the application". As of right now I'm using the following two lines to "move into the application":

```
 let TabBarViewControllerObejct = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController")
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TabBarViewControllerObejct!, animated: true)
```

I would like that response to be available to all views in the Tab Bar Controller, so I attempted to create a class for the TabBarVC and add a property, but when assigning a value to it during the response, it fails and cannot find the property.

I have also tried to push the navController into the first view in the TabBarVC, but then I lose the tab bar.

I tried to use the statements above to instantiate the TBVC and then set a property of that class to the response string. I was unable to assign this properly so I could not access it from within the internal views as required.

I made a Swift file called TabBarController, it subclasses UITabBarController and I pointed the XIB to use that class. I created a response variable in that class and tried to set that property between the statements above.
`TabBarViewControllerObject.responseString = value` which didn't work because I instantiated a UIViewController, not a UITabBarController. I tried to change first statement to include `as! TabBarController`, but then the `pushViewController` function on mismatched types.

Comment: How did you assign the information to the `TabBarViewController`? How did you try to retrieve the data in the `TabBarViewController`

Comment: @KyleRedfearn Edited with an answer

Comment: Please show us that code

Comment: @KyleRedfearn Edited again.

Comment: Immediately after you assigned it, was the value of `TabBarViewControllerObject.responseString` not nil?

Comment: @KyleRedfearn I realized the logic of this method is flawed and instead will use NSUserDefaults to store session data and then retrieve from other views. Thank you for your help otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

After much research it became apparent that I was attempting to engage in rather unsafe memory leaking from one view to another. The eventual decision was to change strategies to use some form of storage to place the response string and then grab from that storage from within the other view.

I turned up some information on `NSUserDefaults`, which (for my situation) worked flawlessly.

To save something into the a store this way:

`import Foundation` to use the NSUserDefaults object

`var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()` to init the defaults

`self.defaults.setObject(VALUE_TO_STORE, forKey: "KEY_NAME")` to store a string with key KEY_NAME and value VALUE_TO_STORE.

then in the other view initialize the defaults the same way and when you want to retrieve that value use
`defaults.stringForKey("KEY_NAME")!`

Hope this helps anyone that got stuck the way I did.